# Detect web browser closed - possible solution

Tags: javascript, html

I have found that there are html events window.onunload and window.onbeforeunload but they really mean that the document is closing/changing.  There doesn't seem to be a general way to detect the web browser closing, which was a surprise.

My application can work in multiple browser tabs so an idea I had was to create a sort of reference counter.  This could work as follows:

When a user launches my web application, in the page onload handler I increment a counter and save the value as a cookie.  ie ++pagecount and save value in cookie.

In window.onunload I decrement the counter (and save new value in cookie).  Not sure if it is possible to have race conditions in saving to a cookie?

When pagecount == 0 I can cleanup.

This would work even in cases where my web application was open in multiple browsers (but of course of same make).

I would appreciate any comments on this?  Do you think this is workable?  Reliable?  Any problems I have not foreseen?

EDIT:
Here is example code of how it might work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function SetCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
   var exdate=new Date();
   exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
   var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
   document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value + ";path=/";
} 

function GetCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function bindEvent(el, eventName, eventHandler) {
   if (el.addEventListener){
        el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false); 
   } else if (el.attachEvent){
        el.attachEvent('on'+eventName, eventHandler);
   }
}

function IncrementUnload() {
   var current = GetCookie("Unloaded") - 0;
   ++current;
   SetCookie("Unloaded", current, 1);

   //here you would compare Loaded and unloaded and if 
   //loaded == unloaded  - then perform any cleanup
}

function printcookie() {
   var here = document.getElementById("here");
   if(here) {
     here.innerHTML += " " + (GetCookie("Loaded") - 0);
   }
}

function printunloadcookie() {
   var there = document.getElementById("there");
   if(there) {
     there.innerHTML += " " + (GetCookie("Unloaded") - 0);
   }
}

function init() {
   var current = GetCookie("Loaded") - 0;
   ++current;
   SetCookie("Loaded", current, 1);
   bindEvent(window, "beforeunload", IncrementUnload);
}

   window.onload = init;

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <b>Close this window or press F5 to reload the page.</b>
    <br /><br />

    <p id="here">Loaded=</p>
    <p id="there">Unloaded=</p>
    <form>
        <input type="button" id="print_cookie" value="print Loaded cookie" onclick="printcookie();">
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="print_unload_cookie" value="print Unloaded cookie" onclick="printunloadcookie();">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you can use localstorage instead of cookies to reduce HTTP request overhead. Generally your method has no problem.

Comment: localstorage is not supported on all browsers (yet) - hence my preference for cookies.  The http overhead of a (probably single digit) number is probably going to be minimal in any case.

Comment: Localstorage is supported by all popular browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE8+, Opera and Safari), so it's not a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a bad idea (or at least it will give you very imprecise numbers):

You can never trust the presence of cookies to be your counting reference. You will not have any race conditions because modern browsers assign different threads to each tab, and each thead will keep their own cookies.

Besides, your web application should be client-agnostic. It should not have any ideas how you are accessing it, as you want to be aware of multiple tabs in a single computer.

I can guess you want this behaviour for either of two things:

1. Better user experience by providing multiple windows for presentation
2. You want to avoid multiple access to the same context

For the first option, you can have modal dialogs in jquery.
For the second option, you always have sessions to control the context of your users.

Hope this helps you decide your approach.

Comment: Why can I never trust the presence of cookies to be my counting reference?

Comment: because cookies are simple text files that can be deleted anytime by maintenance of the machine or the user, is just not reliable